# getting error in joining dictionary with table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, dictionary

I want to have join query from a table with a dictionary based on a common field, my query is:

```
var query = from c in db.Exp
join d in lstUniprotDic on c.UniID equals d.Key
select new
{              
    c.UniID,                        
    IdentityPercent=d.Value.ToString(),
    c.PrId,
    c.SpotNo
}
```

but i got the following error

**Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.**

Answer (score 0):

That pretty much says it all. You can't use the dictionary in your LINQ to SQL query except when using `Contains`.

Solution:

```
(from c in db.Exp where lstUniprotDic.Keys.Contains(c.UniID) select c).AsEnumerable()
join d in lstUniprotDic on c.UniID equals d.Key
select new
{              
    c.UniID,                        
    IdentityPercent=d.Value.ToString(),
    c.PrId,
    c.SpotNo
}
```

I am not sure if the usage of `lstUniprotDic.Keys` in the LINQ to SQL query is actually working.
If not, try using this code instead:

```
var ids = lstUniprotDic.Keys.ToArray();
(from c in db.Exp where ids.Contains(c.UniID) select c).AsEnumerable()
join d in lstUniprotDic on c.UniID equals d.Key
select new
{              
    c.UniID,                        
    IdentityPercent=d.Value.ToString(),
    c.PrId,
    c.SpotNo
}
```

Comment: sorry Daniel but it produces another error you start with `code`(from `code` and end with `code`).AsEnumerable()`code`, VS says query must send be end with select phrase.

Comment: @user3616494: I understood your comment although it is very strange. Please see the fixed version.